# MySQL Time Difference optimization

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization

I'm checking the datetime difference between the current row and the previous one.

Pacific_Time datetime,

id int

```
SELECT A.id, A.Pacific_Time, B.id, B.Pacific_Time, 
A.Pacific_Time - B.Pacific_Time AS Time_Delta from TBL1 A 
JOIN TBL1 B 
ON A.id - 1 =B.id 
WHERE A.Pacific_Time - B.Pacific_Time > 5  
LIMIT 30;
```

I am joining the same table against itself but shifting it one row down or up. Most of the rows are separated by 1 second intervals. I'm searching for rows that are separated by more than 5 seconds. The issue is that when the Pacific_Time goes from second 59 to the 0 second of the following minute it gives a delta of 41 seconds when in reality it is a 1 second difference. Here is an example:

```
A.id    A.Pacific_Time        B.id  B.Pacific_Time        (A.Pacific_Time - B.Pacific_Time )
50      2011-07-19 07:49:55   49    2011-07-19 07:49:54   1.000000
51      2011-07-19 07:49:56   50    2011-07-19 07:49:55   1.000000 
52      2011-07-19 07:49:57   51    2011-07-19 07:49:56   1.000000 
53      2011-07-19 07:49:58   52    2011-07-19 07:49:57   1.000000
54      2011-07-19 07:49:59   53    2011-07-19 07:49:58   1.000000 
55      2011-07-19 07:50:00   54    2011-07-19 07:49:59  41.000000
56      2011-07-19 07:50:01   55    2011-07-19 07:50:00   1.000000
57      2011-07-19 07:50:02   56    2011-07-19 07:50:01   1.000000
58      2011-07-19 07:50:03   57    2011-07-19 07:50:02   1.000000
```

I've tried using the `timediff()` which gives me the correct result but it runs a lot slower. This is running on a table with 20000 rows but it will need to run on a table with near a million rows.

Any advice?

> mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.29, for debian-linux-gnu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> SELECT A.id, A.Pacific_Time, B.id, B.Pacific_Time,  A.Pacific_Time -
>   B.Pacific_Time AS Time_Delta from TBL1 A  JOIN TBL1 B  ON A.id - 1
>   =B.id  WHERE TO_SECONDS(A.Pacific_Time) - TO_SECONDS(B.Pacific_Time) > 5   LIMIT 30;

Please try this query.

Comment: just tried, it runs well better than timediff() but I'm gonna try to investigate how to optimize my mysql setup, buffer size etc.

Answer (score 0):

You have dates stored in datetime format, so instead of treating them as integers use mysql INTERVAL syntax ( from [date-and-time-functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html)):

```
 Date arithmetic also can be performed using INTERVAL together with the + or - operator:

date + INTERVAL expr unit
date - INTERVAL expr unit
```

So your query should look like:

```
SELECT A.id, A.Pacific_Time, B.id, B.Pacific_Time, 
A.Pacific_Time - B.Pacific_Time AS Time_Delta from TBL1 A 
JOIN TBL1 B 
ON A.id - 1 =B.id 
WHERE A.Pacific_Time > B.Pacific_Time + INTERVAL 5 second
LIMIT 30;
```

I may be wrong, but I think with an index on Pacific_Time you can't get any faster.